# Fading in a piece of a Template after it is "shown" using a reactiveVar (meteor.js)

Tags: jquery, css, meteor

I have a view with a Template that has two pieces, a form and then a thank you message.  I want to fade in the thank you message when the form is submitted.  How would I do this?:

```
<template name="inquiry">

{{#if showForm }} 

some form

{{else}} 

        <header class="thank-you fade">
            <h2 class="thank-you">Thank You!</h2>
        </header>

        {{/if}}
```

css:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease;
}
```

I realize this won't work, because the thank you has already been loaded in the DOM.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I'm currently preferring is to have the message always rendered, but add a class when it is invisible. This is easy in your code, as you aren't loading a separate template.

```
<template name="inquiry">

{{#if showForm }} 

some form

{{/if}} 

    <header class="thank-you show-faded {{#if showForm}}hide-faded{{/if}}">
      <h2 class="thank-you">Thank You!</h2>
    </header>
```

And the CSS would be:

```
.hide-faded {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.show-faded {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease;
}
```

Comment: hmm, I'm not seeing the fade effect

Comment: The CSS that you included should still be used. Are you using bootstrap? I had to change the class names as there is a conflict with bootstrap. If you use something like "show-faded" and "hide-faded" instead, then that might work.